# How to query entity from Dynamics AX with X++?

Tags: dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax7

I cannot find any way to query data from Dynamics AX (Finance and Operations). And I searched everywhere with google, they all talked about how to query **table** but not the **entity**.
Anyone who knows how to do it?
If I want to read the data from **AccountantEntity**, how should I do in X++?

Thanks,
Tilerphy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entity refers to [`DataEntityView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/unified-operations/dev-itpro/data-entities/data-entities). They are in AOT - Data Model - Data Entities.

In the X++ you can refer to `AccountantEntity` as any other table/view (your model must have reference to `Application Suite` where entity is defined):

```cs
AccountantEntity accountantEntity;
select firstOnly * from accountantEntity;
```